# WordPress Nested Loops

Tags: wordpress, nested-loops

I've got some code (see below) from an online tutorial that displays an alphabetical list of Category names and then,
underneath each category, a list of post titles for that category.

It works, but I want the post titles to also be displayed alphabetically. At present it's only category names that are alphabetical - see image:

[image: Problem with post title display]

I've done some research online and I think I may need to set up a 'nested loop' - but I have no idea how to edit my code to do this.

Hoping someone can show me how to edit code to get both category names AND post titles to display alphabetically.

This is the code I'm using:

```
// Grab all the categories from the database that have posts.
$categories = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=name&order=ASC');
// Loop through categories
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
   // Display category name
   echo '<h2 class="post-title">' . $category->name . '</h2>';
   echo '<div class="post-list">';
   // WP_Query arguments
   $args = array(
   'cat' => $category->term_id,
   'orderby' => 'term_order',
 );

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
$query->the_post();
?>
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
<?php
} // End while
} // End if
echo '</div>';
// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
} // End foreach
```

Comment: what is the array that stores the post titles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$categories = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=name&order=ASC');
// Loop through categories
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
   // Display category name
   echo '<h2 class="post-title">' . $category->name . '</h2>';
   echo '<div class="post-list">';
   // WP_Query arguments
   $args = array(
   'cat' => $category->term_id,   
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'orderby' => 'title',
 );

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
$query->the_post();
?>
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
<?php
} // End while
} // End if
echo '</div>';
// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
} // End foreach
```

We can add the orderby argument with title.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I was aware of  'orderby' => 'title' but wasn't sure where to place this within the code. I thought it would have to be included in a new, nested query. Guess I was over-complicating things ... again. Much appreciated.